# "Опять-таки" — вводное слово или обстоятельство?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

> Я переругивался с сестрой, пока мы шли к озеру, в которое, опять-таки,
>   с её толчка, нырнул головой.

Ранее в тексте упоминался случай, когда брат упал из-за того, что сестра  толкнула его.
В справочнике по вводным оборотам сказано:

> ОПЯТЬ-ТАКИ, наречие; разг.
>   Неустойчиво вводное, решение об обособлении принимает автор: опять-таки обособляется в функции вводного при желании говорящего привлечь внимание к какому-либо факту (= обратите внимание), интонационно выделяется; не обособляется в функции обстоятельства образа действия (= опять, снова), интонационно не выделяется. Ср.: Это обстоятельство, опять-таки, (= обратите внимание) взывает к комментарию. - Это обстоятельство опять-таки (= опять) взывает к комментарию (Н.Лесков).
>   В функции вводного слова обособляется: Ответ, опять-таки, может быть только один: он неизбежно окажется именно здесь! (М.Булгаков); Разумеется, было бы гораздо проще, если бы я вам показал чертежи; но, разумеется, опять-таки, я еще не склонен это сделать (В.Набоков); Вернувшись тем же путем домой, он обычно находил у себя Марту и, опять-таки, делал все, что от него требовалось (В.Набоков).
>   В функции обстоятельства образа действия не обособляется: Раздался оглушительный, бешеный рев, как бы смешанный вместе со стоном, но... медведь опять-таки не показывался (Н.Лесков); С какими бы процентами заплатили мне все опять-таки высоконравственные дамы за все презрение, которое я всегда чувствовала к их фарисейской нравственности (Н.Лесков).
>   Есть тенденция наречие опять-таки чаще употреблять в функции обстоятельства.

Мне кажется, мой случай подходит под "= обратите внимание", но нужна ли тогда запятая после "с её толчка"?
Как вообще в данном случае нужно распределить знаки?

Comment: @М_Г Извините, мне кажется, что в заголовке правильно написать: "Опять-таки" - **вводное слово**...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, Согласен. Мне только  строчная в начале предложения бросилась в глаза, а про оборот не заметил. Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ранее в тексте упоминался случай, когда брат упал из-за того, что сестра толкнула его.

Значит, он опять нырнул и опять с ее толчка. Имеем  обстоятельство образа действия (= опять, снова), а "с её толчка" не является пояснением и не требует обособления.

**Я переругивался с сестрой, пока мы шли к озеру, в которое опять-таки с её толчка нырнул головой.**

Comment: Нет, до этого он упал не в озеро, а на ровном месте. В таком случае будет сохраняться предложенная вами пунктуация?

Comment: Не стоит считать, что  помощью пунктуации можно выразить конкретные обстоятельства и детали происходящего. Знаки препинания выражают различные отношения в предложении только обобщенно.

Comment: Я все-таки считаю, что пунктуация может менять (передавать) оттенки смысла. А оттенки, оказывается, я неверно понял.  Повторился только толчок, "опять-таки" относится только к нему. В этом случае наилучшим мне кажется предложение @Jasmin: обособить  всё сочетание "**опять-таки с её толчка**". А мое предложение тоже остается в силе, хотя я бы переместил его на второе место. Все остальные варианты считаю неверными.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что три последние запятые не нужны. Если смысл предложения рассматривать с позиций предложенной предыстории, то можно предположить акцент (при помощи слов "опять-таки") на более ранних действиях сестры (когда он угодил с головой в озеро, **именно она** его толкнула). Этим поясняется причина рядовой перебранки: брат с сестрой систематически не ладят, а приводимую в качестве примера уже упоминавшуюся неприятность устроила **она же**. При таком смысле имеет место отсылка *к отдельному члену предложения* (акцент на притяжательном местоимении, а ***не*** на присоединённом высказывании в целом); "опять-таки" заменяется синонимами "именно" или "как раз" (при другом порядке слов "*с её же* толчка"):

> Я переругивался с сестрой, пока мы шли к озеру, в которое **опять-таки** (= *именно, как раз*)
>   с **её** толчка нырнул головой.

Этот случай близок к примеру, в котором фигурируют "опять-таки высоконравственные дамы" (именно такие, как раз такие) - в нём тоже акцентируется отдельный член предложения (определение "высоконравственные").

Comment: Не смею влезать в Ваш ответ, но, думаю, надо подправить: **три** последние запятые не нужны.

Comment: Да, спасибо, не так сосчитал.

Answer (score 2):

**Да, вы правы, здесь именно тот случай,** когда автор, обособляя слово или словосочетание, хочет сказать читателям:  **обратите внимание на эту деталь,** причём имеет на это полное право. Из приведенных ниже примеров видно, что обособление наречия ― это не единичный случай. **Также стоит отметить, что никакой конкретной семантики, кроме выделения и подчеркивания,  это обособление не выражает и не может выразить.**

Но  обособить удобнее всё сочетание ***опять-таки с её толчка.***

Я переругивался с сестрой, пока мы шли к озеру, в которое, **опять-таки с её толчка,** нырнул головой.

Хотя в справочнике "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" указыаается, что наречие ***опять-таки*** не обособляется, но в текстах оно встречается в функции вводного слова, причем для обособления используется как запятая, так  и тире. Также ***опять-таки*** обособляется вместе с другим членом предложения.

**Примеры:**

(1) **Опять-таки,** могу вам дать пример.  [митрополит Антоний (Блум). О молитве (1995)]

(2) И книги читали, классику ― **опять-таки для себя**. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

(3) А он с пола на меня смотрит и говорит, **опять-таки** совершенно спокойно: [Ю. О. Домбровский. Обезьяна приходит за своим черепом, часть 1 (1943-1958)]

(4) Остаются поставки сжиженного природного газа: из Катара, из США и, **опять-таки**, из России. [Сергей Кудияров, «Эксперт», 2014]

(5) **И опять-таки,** во имя чего ждать? Ждать, когда нет сил жить, а между тем жить нужно и хочется жить! [А. П. Чехов. Крыжовник (1898)]

В приведенных примерах обособление ***опять-таки*** соответствует структуре предложения (выбрана позиция, удобная для обособления), но вот в предложении (4) обособление **факультативное, авторское.** В заданном предложении обособление также является **факультативным**.

Comment: Мне Ваш ответ ближе и понятнее: я рассуждала так же.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку, для меня это очень важно.